# WebConfigurationManager or HttpContext.Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, configuration, httpcontext

I'm a beginner with C#, .net etc., and I am working with a MVC Web Application.

I saw some examples where, in `Application_Start()` in Global.asax.cs, people use `Application.Add("prop", "value")` to store values from Web.config.

Then we can access it in the controllers, through `HttpContext.Application["prop"]`.

Is there a difference between using

```
HttpContext.Application["prop"]
```

and using

```
WebConfigurationManager["prop"]
```

?

I think in this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx it is advised to use `WebConfigurationManager` for Web applications, but they don't talk about `HttpContext.Application`.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Both have different purposes**.

The `HttpContext.Application` represents [HttpApplicationState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which you can think about as a set of application level global variables. It is stored in-memory and not persisted to disk, so it's lost if the worker process is restarted.

On the other hand, the `WebConfigurationManager` is used to access the Web.Config file. It is stored on disk and persisted when the app pool is recycled.

For the particular case you are describing, I suppose someone may have thought that there was a performance benefit in loading the properties from Web.Config into memory and accessing them from memory, although I'm not convinced that much of a performance benefit will be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `HttpApplicationState` to store and retrieve values, no writing to the web.config file is done - indeed, it's likely already been loaded for that request anyway. What you're doing is storing it in some form of cache that exists as long as the lifetime of the application.

With a configuration manager, that will write to the underlying configuration file (of that instance) when a call to `Save` is made.

Basically, these are different things although they could seem to function to you, the user, in the same way.